# How can I uncompress gz files in random directories and store the decompressed files in those same directories?

Tags: bash, centos

CentOS 5.9

I've got a server with a foo.ext.gz file located in a variety of random directories.

Example:

- /opt/fooapp/foosubdirectory/foo_randomnumber/blah/blah/foo.ext.gz
- /opt/fooapp/foosubdirectory/foo_differentrandomnumber/blah/blah/foo.ext.gz
- /opt/fooapp/foosubdirectory/foo_anotherdifferentrandomnumber/blah/blah/foo.ext.gz

I'd like to run a bash command that will:

1. Locate foo.ext.gz files
2. Extract the contents of the gz file **in the same directory that its respective GZ file resides in**
3. Keep the original gz file intact.

If I was doing this manually, I'd start with `find / -iname foo.ext.gz`.  After that, I'd copy the directory the file resides in and type something like:

```
gunzip -c /opt/fooapp/foosubdirectory/foo_12345/blah/blah/foo.ext.gz  > /opt/fooapp/foosubdirectory/foo_12345/blah/blah/foo.ext
```

The problem here is that I need to manually do this process for several dozen files/directories.

Is there a way I can leverage xargs or a for loop?

Comment: I rolled back the edits, as I saw they collided with your own edit. But yours remove the differences between the various directories. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 5):

Although you can parse the output from a `find` you have to take care of spaces etc. Unfortunately `gunzip` does not have a `--keep`/`-k` flag for keeping (like `bzip2` and `xz` do have).

If would make a small script `gunzipkeep` that takes one parameter (the gzipped file) and does the decompression, put that script somewhere in your $PATH and call it with:

```
find /opt/fooapp/foosubdirectory -name "foo.ext.gz" -print0 | xargs -0 --norun-if-empty --max-args 1 gunzipkeep
```

The script could be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
inname=$1
outname=${inname%.gz}

gunzip -c "$inname" > "$outname"
```

Comment: Thanks Anthon but I'm not quite following you on the script part.  Wouldn't a script with gunzip still wipe away the original gz file?

Comment: I added a script, it includes the `-c` option like you used it, so it keeps the original. Essential the scripts expands the single argument for you. You could change it so that it does a for loop and remove the `--max-args` argument to xargs for efficiency, but that is probably minor compared to the time gunzip takes

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to do this without using an helper script (or a bash function) as done in another answer but not impossible.
Here using `-execdir` option of `find` and some `bash` parameter expansion.

```
find /opt/fooapp/foosubdirectory -name '*.gz' -execdir /bin/bash -c 'pwd ; echo ${0%.gz}; cp ${0} ${0%.gz}.tmp.gz ; gunzip ${0%.gz}.tmp.gz ; mv ${0%.gz}.tmp ${0%.gz}' {} \;
```

[edit] NOTE: you need a recent version of `bash` (for this particular parameter exparsion), some older versions does not have this features. I tested this on a V 3.2.x

[Edit] NOTE2 : The `-execdir` expression, as far I know, is present into GNU `find` (and other modern implementations) but not into older ones. I testet this on GNU find v 4.2.x

The same rewitten for readability & comment:

```
find /opt/fooapp/foosubdirectory 
     -name '*.gz'
     -execdir /bin/bash -c '_bash_command_string_ ' {} \;
# This ^ will run bash from the subdirectory containing the matched file

  _bash_command_string_  --> 
      pwd ;                       # we are working in this subdir 
      echo ${0%.gz};              # this is matched filename (minus final .gz)
      cp ${0} ${0%.gz}.tmp.gz ;   # copy the .gz file as .tmp.gz
      gunzip ${0%.gz}.tmp.gz ;    # gunzip the .tmp.gz as .tmp
      mv ${0%.gz}.tmp ${0%.gz}    # rename .tmp as matched filename (minus final .gz)
```

This solution is interesting as an clever hack but probably too complex to be used in pratice.

See [Bash Reference - Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) , search  `${parameter%word}` .

Answer (score 1):

With bash ≥4, run `shopt -s extglob` to make `**/` traverse directories recursively. (Beware that this traverses symbolic links to directories. In zsh, you don't need any special setup, and `**/` doesn't descend into symlinks, but `***/` does.) Then a simple loop suffices:

```
err=
for z in **/*.gz; do
  gunzip <"$z" >"${z%.gz}" &&
  touch -r "$z" "${z%.gz}" ||    # if you want to retain the file's modification time
  err=1
done
if [ -n "$err" ]; then echo >&1 'Watch out, there were errors!'; fi
```

With only a POSIX `sh`, invoke a shell from `find`. It's more difficult to extract the error status — check if the command produces anything on stderr.

```
find . -name '*.gz' -exec sh -c '
  for z do gunzip <"$z" >"${z%.gz}" && touch -r "$z" "${z%.gz}"; done
' _ {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name \*.gz | parallel gzip -dc {} \> {.}
```

- `{.}` is an input line without an extension
- The default delimiter is just linefeed

```
find . -name \*.gz | while read f; do gzip -dc "$f" > "${f%.gz}"; done
```

- Add `IFS=` or `-r` if the input lines can start or end with characters in IFS or if they can contain backslashes